# Collecting data on private rooftop characteristics?

Tags: legal, real-estate, privacy

Is it legal to save data about **private** rooftop terraces in a Open Data set? I mean: location, characteristics, etc.

Comment: It really depends on a lot of factors. The most important thing is probably the laws in your country, province/state, and municipality.

Comment: :) Thanks for your response! How would you search for this information in your country? Do you know where find it? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: even if it is legal, think about the ethics here. people have a right to privacy.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia, a federal government agency (PSMA) has created a for-cost dataset called  [Geoscape](https://www.psma.com.au/geoscape) that calculates information on private rooftops: specifically roof heights and materials.

I wanted to post this as an answer to show a precedent for private rooftop characteristics and locations, albeit for a cost.